Form loses focus and can't be dragged after deleting TFrame
I have a small issue with window focus and I'm not sure if the issue is even in focus, because I can't find any working solutions.
I have a TBaseFrame class which is basically a TFrame, and a TFrameContainer which handles displaying different frames.
I add a frame manually from code to layout by calling AddObject in the container code.
By clicking on Button2 an event is invoked and the container removes the current frame and changes it to a different frame.
Closing is done the same. But than a strange thing happens. The window sort of 'loses focus' or something. I can't drag it or close without switching to another window and then back.
Closing code:
procedure TFrameContainer.OnFrameClosed();
begin

  case CurrentFrame.FrameType of
    Master:
      begin

      end;
    Child:
        begin
          Holder.RemoveObject(CurrentFrame);//Remove frame here from layout
          FramesPath.Remove(CurrentFrame);

          CurrentFrame.OnClose;
          CurrentFrame.DisposeOf;

          CurrentFrame := FramesPath.Last;
          Holder.AddObject(CurrentFrame);


        end;
    ChildWindowed:
      begin
        if Assigned(ParentForm) then
          begin
            ParentForm.Close;
          end;
      end;
  end;
end;

How can I give a window's 'focus' back? Also note that I might not have any controls on a frame.
How it looks:


Hard to say without seeing how TFrameContainer is being used in relation to the UI. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows the problem in action.

Instead of removing the frame object try using CurrentFrame.Release;. It's difficult to make out how everything is structured but I'm assuming you're trying to close the frame within itself.

Already did this and it worked, but yeah thanks!

As soon as I posted the question I found a solution in this post (Delphi FMX) How can I refresh my Frame Object inside a TabControl.TabItem without losing control of the window?.
But I swear I looked for answer for days :/
The short answer is window stopped responding to dragging or pressing Close button because I tried to free a frame in OnClick method of a button. Button it self contained in this frame so it frees with frame without finishing OnClick method.
Also English is not my first language so I'm sorry for mistakes.
